# Why is Fourier Analysis effective for studying uniform distributions

Tags: fourier-analysis, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta, motivation

On his great expository [article](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~wtg10/zetafunction.ps) about the naturality of the Zeta function in number theory, Tim Gowers makes the following claim:

> When it comes to the primes, we find that we do not have a good feeling for which numbers are primes, but we do know of a very interesting property that they have - the fundamental theorem of arithmetic. As for what we are trying to prove, some sort of uniform distribution, it suggests the use of Fourier analysis. (If it does not suggest to you the use of Fourier analysis, then you should read another of my essays, which unfortunately doesn't exist yet, "What is natural about Fourier analysis?")

Well, it didn't to me, and as far as I know the said essay hasn't been written yet.

I can follow what comes after, up to the heuristic explanation of the proof of the prime number theorem, but the methods all seem a bit magical.

What is it about uniform distributions that makes the technology of transforms, convolutions, Hilbert spaces, etc so effective?

Comment: think to the Euler product as the Laplace transform of an infinite convolution product of many distributions representing each prime number localization. as you now, even if an elementary proof of the prime number theorem has been found, in the real world what allowed us to understand the prime number theorem (a theorem about the regularity of primes distribution) and its extension/improvement the Riemann hypothesis is exactly that Euler product formulation of $\zeta(s)$, itself the Laplace transform of the distribution representing the logarithm of the integers localization.

Comment: Only syntactically related, maybe (?): http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/12678/why-does-fourier-analysis-of-boolean-functions-work

Comment: Weyl's equidistribution criterion?

Comment: do you understand everything I wrote in my comment ? because after that, it becomes much more complicated : how to interpret automorphic forms and such things.

Comment: @user1952009 I think I do, but that's not quite what I was asking. My question is why things that are uniformly distributed are so fruitfully attacked by the machinery of fourier analysis. Once that's settled, I can agree that Dirichlet series are the natural generating functions for number theoretical problems, Euler product or not, because their convolution rule translates the combinatorial problem of counting over different factorizations.

Comment: What is uniformly distributed ? Because at first the Laplace transform is useful for trying to prove or disprove that $\pi(e^u) - \frac{e^u}{u} = \mathcal{O}(e^{(\sigma+\epsilon)u})$ : if $F(s) = \int_0^\infty f(u) e^{-su}du$ has a singularity at $\sigma+it$, then clearly $f(u) \ne  \mathcal{O}(e^{(\sigma-\epsilon)u})$

Comment: I'm thinking of something more basic and first principles than that. If we want to understand the asymptotics of a subset of the natural numbers, why would it suddenly be useful to consider projections, orthonormal sequences, convolutions, etc? Why is Fourier analysis the natural weapon of choice (besides that it works)? To put it in another way, why would Dirichlet choose fourier analytic tools to try and tackle primes in arithmetic progressions?

Comment: @FelipeJacob: After having read Gowers' text, I tend to disagree with him: convolutions and Fourier machinery are the natural thing to use only if one has already been exposed to them. Otherwise, we wouldn't have waited till the 20th century to develop this approach to Riemann's Zeta. This is the typical mental deformation that one experiences when diving deeply into a subject, no matter how weird: this one tends to become natural. I've encountered somebody claiming that the $p$-adic distance is more natural (!) than the Euclidian one. He was working in $p$-adic analysis, obviously...

Comment: @AlexM. One trouble I've had while learning number theory is that some techniques like Gauss sums seem like incredibly clever tricks made to tackle specific problems. What Gowers did for me is show that even if history had happened otherwise, these ideas would have eventually emerged when we tried to transfer knowledge from other areas of mathematics to number theoretical problems. Nonetheless, I'd be really interested to see a more "classical" argument for the naturality of defining the Zeta function and studying it's complex analytic properties to tackle prime numbers (besides that it works)

Comment: This reminds me of the [Central Limit Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem) and the fact that [for the unitary Fourier transforms, the Gaussian is its own Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Square-integrable_functions,_one-dimensional).